# What are the first non-maximal non-group-subgroup simple irreducible subfactors?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

*[Definition](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-50/issue-2/Normal-intermediate-subfactors/10.2969/jmsj/05020469.full)*: For an irreducible (finite index) subfactor $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M})$, an intermediate $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{M})$
is **normal** if the biprojections $e_{\mathcal{P}}$ and $e_{\mathcal{P}'}$ are central in the $2$-boxes spaces of $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M})$ and $(\mathcal{M}' \subset \mathcal{N}')$.   Note that if these $2$-boxes spaces are abelian, then every intermediate is normal.

*Remark*: because  Teruya's definition of *normal* uses $(\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{M}_1)$ instead of $(\mathcal{M}' \subset \mathcal{N}')$, for more caution (but I believe it's not necessary), the factors are supposed to be isomorphic to the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factor, or at least are supposed to be anti-isomorphic to themselves (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110158v2.pdf) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/915314/84284)).

*Examples*: for $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{M})$ with $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M})$ isomorphic to the tensor **or** the free composition of $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{P})$ and $(\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{M})$, then $\mathcal{P}$ is a normal intermediate. For the group-subgroup subfactor of $(H \subset G)$, the normal intermediate subfactors are given by the intermediate subgroups $K$ with   $HgK=KgH$, $\forall g \in G$. For a group subfactor, they are then given the normal subgroups.

*Definition*: An irreducible subfactor $(\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M})$ is **simple** if it admits no non-trivial normal intermediate.

*Examples*:  The maximal subfactors are simple. A group subfactor is simple iff the group is simple.
The *first* non-trivial non-maximal  group-subgroup simple subfactor  are indices $20$, $20$, $21$, $28$, given by:
$(\mathbb{Z}_3 \subset A_5)$, $(S_3  \subset S_5)$, $(D_8 \subset G)$ and $(S_3 \subset G)$ with $G = PSL(2,7)$.

**Question**: What are the first non-maximal non-group-subgroup simple irreducible subfactors?
(also non-[Kac-coideal](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179838/34538), because $(\mathbb{Z}_3 \subset A_5)$ could admit a simple non-trivial Kac deformation)

*Remark*: for the irreducible subfactors of index $<6$, the depth 1-2 edges of the principal graphs (and dual) are multiplicity one, so the $2$-boxes spaces are abelian, so all the biprojections are central, and so all the intermediates are normal; it follows that they can't be simple and non-maximal.

Comment: what you mean by "first"?

Comment: @DavePenneys: the "first" such subfactors regarding to the index. Nevertheless the first discovered or just an example, would be still interesting.

Comment: Whoops - I answered before I saw "non-maximal," so I deleted my answer. Have you checked the affine $A$'s yet? They are the first possible examples.

Comment: @DavePenneys: For every irreducible subfactors of index $< 6$, the depth $1$-$2$ edges of the  principal graph (and dual) are multiplicity one, so the $2$-boxes spaces are abelian, so all the biprojections are central, so all the intermediates are normal; it follows that they can't be simple and non-maximal.

Comment: See also: [Are the integer index finite depth irreducible subfactors Kac-coideal?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/179838/34538)

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the question. Even if you were to look at reducible subfactors, the affine A's are not examples. Even though they have non-abelian 2-boxes, the biprojection (coming from the affine D planar subalgebra) is central.