# Is a finite depth-index irreducible subfactor, intermediate of a depth ≤ 3 one?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

Let $(N \subset M)$ be a finite depth-index irreducible subfactor.

**Main question**: Is $(N \subset M)$ the intermediate of a finite index depth $\le 3$  irreducible subfactor?
(In others words, is there $P \subset N$ or $Q \supset M$ such that $(P \subset M)$ or $(N \subset Q)$ is a finite index depth $\le 3$ irreducible subfactor?)

*Remark*: By the prop. 9.1.1 p 37 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006057v2), an irreducible finite depth-index subfactor is always an intermediate subfactor of a depth $2$ **reducible** subfactor. But, this post asks if it is always the intermediate of a finite index depth $\le 3$ **irreducible** subfactor.

*Remark*: the first examples to look at should be the $A_n$-subfactors (of depth $n-1$).
It's ok for $n=2,3,4$; for $n=5$ also: it's isomorphic to $(R^{S_3} \subset R^{S_2})$, intermediate of $(R^{S_3} \subset R)$.
*Question*: Is $A_6$ a counter-example? If yes, why? Else, is it true for all $n \ge 2$ ?

*Definition*:  A finite index depth $d$ irreducible subfactor $(N \subset M)$ is called **top** if  it can't be the intermediate of a strictly smaller depth subfactor (in others words, such a subfactor is *top* if $\forall P \subset N$ and $\forall Q \supset M$ such that $(P \subset M)$ and $(N \subset Q)$ are irreducible, then their depths are $\ge d$).

*Examples*: A group-subgroup subfactor is top iff it's a group subfactor.
The non-integer index depth $3$ irreducible subfactors are top.

The question [Are the integer index finite depth irreducible subfactors Kac-coideal?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179838/34538) is reformulable by: Are the integer index finite depth irreducible *top* subfactors, depth $2$?

The *main question* is also reformulable by:  Is a finite depth-index irreducible *top* subfactor, depth $\le 3$?

---

**Optional part**: *top-simple reduction*

If the main question admits a negative answer:
*Question*: Is there an irreducible finite index top subfactor of arbitrary large depth $d$?
If yes, is there one for all $d \ge 2$?

*Remark*: The classification of the subfactors reduces to the classification of the top subfactors, because all the others come as intermediates.

Let $(N \subset M)$ be a  finite depth-index irreducible top subfactor, and $(N \subset P \subset M)$  an intermediate.
*Question*: $P$ [normal](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179788/34538) $\Rightarrow$ depth$(N \subset P)$, depth$(P \subset M) \le$  depth$(N \subset M)$?
*Remark*:  For the depth $2$ case, it's true and the converse also.  Is it also an equivalence at depth $d$?

*Question*: Does the [Jordan-Hölder theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156311/34538) work for the finite depth-index irreducible top subfactors?
*Remark*: [this anwser](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161951/34538) shows that, *without the top assumption*, Jordan-Hölder theorem does not work, counter-examples are given the $(A_n \subset S_{n+1})$ group-subgroup subfactors (for $n \ge 3$).

If the two previous questions admit positive answers then the classification of the depth $\le d$ finite index irreducible subfactors reduces to the top [simple](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179788/34538)  ones.

Comment: I guess, an irreducible finite index finite depth subfactor is always an intermediate subfactor of a depth 2 reducible subfactor.

Comment: What let you think that every finite depth subfactor is intermediate of an irreducible depth $\leq 3$ guy??

Comment: Ok, I think for $A_n$ subfactors this is clear, still not sure how this should work in general...

Comment: What's your argument for $A_n$, $n\ge 6$?

Comment: What let me know is for example the paper [Quantum subgroups of the Haagerup fusion categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2631v2) of Grossman-Snyder in which the Haagerup subfactor and its Izumi generalizations, appear at intermediate of depth $3$ irreducible  subfactors. In general, such irreducible depth $3$ "reduction" seems possible via this quantum subgroups way.

Comment: Actually I just have an argument for $n$ even.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff:  Could you sketch your argument for n even?